# python: Argument list too long

Tags: python, php, linux, ubuntu

I am working on a PHP back that uses python scripts. In PHP, queries and processes are carried out that at the end are passed as arguments to the script, a string is created with the command that is finally executed with exec ()

```
$arg4Json= str_replace("'", "Â´", json_encode($arg4));
$command = "python ../path/of/file"
    . "/script.py {$arg1} "
    . "{$arg2} {$arg3} '{$arg4Json}'";    
$output = null;
$returnVal = null;
exec($command, $output, $returnVal);
```

This was working perfectly. However, in a certain query the arg4Json turns out to be too long and the service crashes. Try to run the command directly in the console with the same arguments and it returns the message:

> python: Argument list too long

I have investigated about it and apparently it is a matter related to the maximum length allowed by the console to execute the command and that it is necessary to increase the limits. In the end I was able to increase the 'stack size' and leave it unlimited to test if it worked but it keeps throwing me the same error.

[ulimit_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHdOq.jpg)

I would appreciate if someone can guide me on how I can solve this problem. The project runs on a linux server with ubuntu on Apache2.

Comment: Does php have a version of `exec` that takes a command and an list of arguments instead of a string that combines them all?

Comment: Can you put the very long argument into a temporary file, and then have Python read the file?  Or even read the long argument as standard input.

Comment: Linux does not let you put more than 128k in a single argument, regardless of the stack size.

Answer (score 0):

why not put arguments in a file. and change the behaviour of your program to read arguments from the file instead of passing them as arguments. it's more efficient i think